# How to add items to a side menu bar?

Tags: ios, xcode6

Im making my first app. My app will have a side pop out menu. I have gotten the sliding menu part implemented with a UITableView. Now i want to populate the side menu with text and a image next to it and when one is tapped i want to push another view controller. What would be the best way to do this? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add row in a TableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496699/add-row-in-a-tableview)

Answer (score 0):

As user132490 said, you probably want to add rows to your tableView. Here's a tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/. It's for Xcode 5 but still will work. You may find it useful from "Adding Table Data" and below. In fact, before the Summary the tutorial teaches you to add a thumbnail next to the text of each of your cells.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have an image and text for your table, you have to create a `UITableViewCell` subclass and declare an image view and label. Image view and label must be created in IB, create a prototype cell and add there the image view and label.

Once you've done that you must have an array of what will be the content of your table. It's like this:

In `@interface`:

```
@property NSMutableArray *menuArray;
```

In your `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSDictionary *option1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"image1.png",@"image",@"Option1",@"desc", nil];

    NSDictionary *option2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"image2.png",@"image",@"Option2",@"desc", nil];

    NSDictionary *option3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"image3.png",@"image",@"Option3",@"desc", nil];

    NSDictionary *option4 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"image4.png",@"image",@"Option4",@"desc", nil];

    NSDictionary *option5 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"image5.png",@"image",@"Option5",@"desc", nil];


    //assign NSDictionaries to array
    self.menuArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:option1,option2,option3,option4,option5, nil];
```

And then you must have table view delegate methods like this:

```
#pragma mark Table View delegate methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return  [menuArray count];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    //return row height
    return 32;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";

    //assign TableCell.h to access custom properties
    TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    //get dictionary from menuArray
    NSDictionary * dict = [self.menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIImage *imageIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:[dict objectForKey:@"image"]];
    //set image
    [cell.img setImage:imageIcon];
    //set the label text
    cell.label.text = [dict objectForKey:@"desc"];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //research more about pushing another view controller.

    //if chosen was option1
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        NSLog(@"option1");
    }

    //if chosen was option2
    if (indexPath.row == 1) 
    {
        NSLog(@"option2");
    }

    //if chosen was option3
    if (indexPath.row == 2) 
    {
        NSLog(@"option3");
    }

    // if chosen was option4
    if(indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        NSLog(@"option4");
    }

    // if chosen is option5
    if(indexPath.row == 4)
    {
        NSLog(@"option5");
    }
}
```

In pushing to other view controller, try to research more because it's a lot more explanation. Try this link: https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController

But with this codes, you must be able to populate your table and when you select a cell there will be a log. Hope this helps :)